# Error while Unmarshalling XML using JAXB/Spring OXM

Tags: spring, xsd, jaxb, jaxb2, oxm

I am trying to convert xsd to Java objects using xjc. classes are generated.
But when i try to unmarshall an sample xml file to java object using spring OXM, it fails with the below error.

```
org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: JAXB unmarshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"urn:validfilenotification", local:"ValidFileNotification"). Expected elements are <{urn:notificationbase}ActionRequestedGrp>,<{urn:notificationbase}DocTypeIndicCd>,<{urn:notificationbase}FATCANotificationCd>,<{urn:notificationbase}FATCANotificationHeaderGrp>,<{urn:notificationbase}FATCAReportTypeCd>,<{urn:notificationbase}FieldErrorGrp>,<{urn:notificationbase}FileTypeCd>,<{urn:notificationbase}MessageTypeCd>,<{urn:notificationbase}OriginalFileMessageSpecGrp>,<{urn:notificationbase}OriginalFileMetadataGrp>,<{urn:notificationbase}OriginalFileProcessingDataGrp>,<{urn:notificationbase}OriginalPaperRecordMetadataGrp>,<{urn:notificationbase}PaperRecordDocumentTypeCd>,<{urn:notificationbase}RecordLevelErrorCd>,<{urn:notification
```

can somebody point what am i doing wrong.